# What's the word or phrase that means a TV show is suitable for a family to watch together?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

What's the word or phrase that means a TV show is suitable for a family to watch together, i.e., there's no NSFW content? The show does not have to be a cartoon or something like that which is typical for kids. The key point here is that it doesn't contain sussy stuff in any form.

Comment: There's a single letter typo: it should be **sassy**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 'sussy baka' ?

Comment: @BCLC How would "contain sussy baka" make any sense? It's *sassy stuff*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Try searching 'sussy cartoon' in YouTube and you will find some inappropriate cartoon moments. It's not a typo. This usage of 'sussy' or 'sus' is quite new, I think.

Comment: Well I never. I've heard of "**sus** *someone/ something* **out**" which means to discover the truth or understand a person's character or lies. This "sussy" is totally new to me. Probably American English.

Comment: I don't think you're the term is being used appropriately. [Online I read this explanation](https://dotcomstories.com/sussy-baka-meaning/) for **sussy baka** “Sussy is a character from the wildly popular online game Among Us, which was extremely popular in the early Pandemic days. In the game, players would refer to someone as “sus” for “suspicious” if they believed them to be an imposter. In contrast, the Japanese word “Baka” denotes “fool” or “silly.” Therefore, you can refer to someone as a “Sussy Baka” if you ever think they are foolish or silly (affectionately or derogatorily).”

Comment: [Elsewhere](https://newsrelationship.com/sussy-baka-meaning-origin/): “… *a lot of you are already aware [that] "sussy" or "sus," a term popularized in the game "Among Us." Sussy is used to describe a person who is an "imposter" in the game, while 'baka" is derived from the Japanese language, which means "fool." So the expression basically means "Suspicious fool."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Family-friendly' or 'family friendly'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-friendly